# Modal Popup with dynamic IDs

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my code

```
$sql = "select * from billbook where stcode =? and sem =?";
$query = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$query->bind_param('si',$stcode, $sem);
$query->execute();
$query->store_result();
$query->bind_result($billno,$billdate,$stcode,$sem,$amount);
$x = 1;
while($query->fetch())
{
?>
    <tr>
        <td align='center'><?php echo $x ?></td>
        <td align='center' id="bno"><a href=""><?php echo $billno ?></a></td>
        <td align='center'><?php echo $billdate?></td>
        <td align='right'><?php echo $amount?>.00</td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

My aim is to show the details of the Bill Number in a Modal Dialog Popup in Bootstrap,  when the user click the "**bno**" ID (Second Column), after processing the details in an external PHP file.
Please Help.

Comment: Please post your Bootstrap code, so we can help. Refer this "Loading remote page" part in http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/ for reference. If you are using this.

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap CDN

Answer (score 1):

```
<td align="center" id="bno"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#billno-<?= $billno ?>"><?= $billno ?></a></td>

<?php
// generate a modal per bill
$modals[] = array(
    'billno'                => $billno,
    'modal_id'              => 'billno-'.$billno,
    'title'                 => 'Bill No. '.$billno,
    'message'               => 'Modal body here',
    'dismiss_button_text'   => 'Close'
);
?>

...

<?php foreach ($modals as $modal) : ?>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="billno-<?= $modal['billno'] ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><?= $modal['title'] ?></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p><?= $modal['message'] ?></p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success form-control" data-dismiss="modal"><?= $modal['dismiss_button_text'] ?></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: For one record its OK, But for multiple records, its not working.

Comment: It shows an error message "<div class="modal fade" id="billno-<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in"

Comment: Thank you very much @codecrunch.
But I want the result in the Modal dialog, which is from an external PHP file.
When we click the bill number, I need to extract the details from an external PHP file. So I want to pass the bill number to that PHP file.